# iOS app stopped reliably loading questions/answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Not every time, but sometimes when I select a question from the Feed, the circle just spins forever without loading the question. Selecting the answers tab does the same thing.

---

At 6:52 I selected the question

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5cth.png]

It kept spinning until I took the next screenshot at 6:54

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWmlN.png]

At which point I switched to the answers tab

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RSYx.png]

This is new to 0.1.46. It happens about half the time, and I'm mostly seeing it from the Feed.

Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Thanks for the report.  I'll have a look.

Comment: BTW, I've deleted and re-downloaded the app, and restarted the phone. No dice. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @user258227 can you check again in 0.1.47? Looks like it fixed this specific problem.

Comment: @shadow, yup, just went through a dozen questions in a row without any failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This turns out to be (I'm reasonably sure) to be a fouled up access token, specific to the user.  I believe this issue to be resolved.</strike>

Looks like there was actually a second issue going on that affected more than just this user, and it looks like the newest build (`0.1.47`) has fixed it (credit to @Arie and @Brian).

Comment: thanks so much for your help! i had figured something like that would have reset on deleting and re-downloading the app, but i'll keep an eye on it

Comment: Reproduced for me as well, since upgrading to 0.1.46

Comment: Me too. Also since the same version mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you join me in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/705/ios-)?  I'll be there for about another 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for quick and efficient fix, you can safely mark this completed as OP [confirmed too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228922/ios-app-stopped-reliably-loading-questions-answers?noredirect=1#comment751635_228922). :-)